# get specific strings from html file

Tags: php, html

i tried to get specific string from html file, i already get the file name. but i want get piece of string from the different file name. here's the example i was tried.

html

```
<TABLE class="tab1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;Start RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;File:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;WALUYO GROUP (LUTFI) - 240 - 
 ITHINK\T7\T7-FROZ-45X163 - 20 PCS.tif&nbsp; &nbsp;
 </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE class="tab1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;Start RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;File:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp; Gigas G - 100x100 - 1x.tif&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

CODE I TRIED,

```
foreach (glob("C://xampp/htdocs/Log/Flora/*.HTML")as $html1)
{ 
if (file_exists($html1)) 
{ 
$source1 = file_get_contents($html1);
$dom1 = new DOMDocument();
$dom1->loadHTML($source1);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom1);
$textList1 = $xpath->query("//table");
    foreach ( $textList1 as $text1 )
{
    $files   = $xpath->evaluate(

"string(descendant::tr[th[contains(text(),'File')]]/td/text())",
                   $text1);
        $threee  = $files;
    $query = "INSERT INTO CMP.LOG_FILE(FIL_NM) VALUES 
('".utf8_decode($threee)."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
}}}
```

RESULT :

```
1. WALUYO GROUP (LUTFI) - 240 - ITHINK\T7\T7-FROZ-45X163 - 20 PCS.tif
2. Gigas G -100x100- 1x.tif
```

Now i want is just get the size, ex:

```
1. 45X163
2. 100x100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the part of size string like this.

```
$pattern = "/- ?(\d+[Xx]\d+) ?-/";
preg_match($pattern, $files, $matches) ;
print($matches[1]) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if all of your filenames so kindly contain the size in just that way, and no additional size-like strings, I would just go with:

```
$size = preg_match('/(\d+x\d+)/', $filename, $match) ? $match[1] : "Not found";
```

If you have a formal definition for the size component within the filename, you could refine the pattern.  For example, if spaces are allowed (240 x 240), you could change it to:

```
$size = preg_match('/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)/', $filename, $match) ? ($match[1].'x'.$match[2]) : "Not found";
```

And so forth.  However, having said that, if you have access to the files, you could also use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to actually get the size of the image rather than depend on the filename.  So:

```
$filesize = getimagesize($filepath);
$size = $filesize[0].'x'.$filesize[1];
```

Comment: Yes.  Using the second preg_match example, you can multiply $match[1] * $match[2] to get that.  I added the getimagesize use case. You can also multiply $filesize[0] * $filesize[1] in that example.

Comment: <TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;47.0 x 173.0cm&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>........ how about this, i dont understand preg match

Comment: I think an explanation of regular expressions and how they are implemented in PHP is probably beyond the scope (and length!) of a comment, but you can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) - its probably worth your time if you are planning to dissect filenames and the like.  I actually prefer the getimagesize in this case - filenames which are supposed to tell you about the files are usually notoriously unreliable, and its easy enough to get the image size from the file content.